# looking for indoxploit hack solution

Tags: hacked

On our WordPress powered website we have only 1 user:
ID: 1
username: is not admin

WordPress working with latest version, theme and plugins are all updated to the latest.

username and password is hacked and both set to indoxploit

I have reset username and password by phpMyAdmin

i googled https://www.google.com/search?q=indoxploit it seems there is an exploit named indoxploit

Please advice how can I prevent this hack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by BBQ: Block Bad Queries plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/block-bad-queries/